# valgrind android doesn't show line numbers

Tags: android-ndk, valgrind, android-debug

On Android shell:

```
/data/local/valgrind/enter code herebin/valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --log-file=/sdcard/valgrind.log /data/local/Test
```

========================================================================

valgrind.log--HEAP SUMMARY:

==21314== HEAP SUMMARY:

==21314==     in use at exit: 2,098,270 bytes in 6 blocks

==21314==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 0 frees, 2,098,270 bytes allocated

==21314==

==21314== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 6

==21314==    at 0x482BAEC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)

==21314==    by 0x864B: ??? (in /data/local/Test)

==21314==

==21314== 10 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 6

==21314==    at 0x482BAEC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)

==21314==    by 0x863B: ??? (in /data/local/Test)

==21314==

==21314== 80 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 6

==21314==    at 0x482C2E4: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:378)

==21314==    by 0x85DF: ??? (in /data/local/Test)

==21314==

==21314== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6

==21314==    at 0x482BAEC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)

==21314==    by 0x4852DB3: __smakebuf (in /system/lib/libc.so)

==21314==

==21314== 1,048,576 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5 of 6

==21314==    at 0x482BAEC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)

==21314==    by 0x86C3: ??? (in /data/local/Test)

==21314==

==21314== 1,048,576 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6

==21314==    at 0x482BAEC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)

==21314==    by 0x869F: ??? (in /data/local/Test)

==21314==

==21314== LEAK SUMMARY:

==21314==    definitely lost: 1,048,670 bytes in 4 blocks

==21314==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==21314==      possibly lost: 1,048,576 bytes in 1 blocks

==21314==    still reachable: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks

==21314==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==21314==

==21314== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v

==21314== ERROR SUMMARY: 137 errors from 18 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

the Android.mk:

> ```
>    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
>    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
>    LOCAL_MODULE    := Test
>
>    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloworld.cpp
>
>    APP_CPPFLAGS  += -O0
>
>    include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)**
> ```

On Linux I run `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1` so this Test is debugable, why doesn't the valgrind log show the line numbers?

Comment: I found a solution ; use the /projectDIR/obj/local/armeabi/Test, Do not use the /projectDIR/libs/armeabi/Test . Because the former not have Symbols, the latter have Symbols ;Andriod app yet !

Comment: For best results, you also want to have versions of the system libraries with symbols installed.